# Method is not visible to print details on Snakes and Ladders Game

Tags: java, methods, 2d

```
public class CA {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int[][] numbersOnBoard = new int[6][6];
    boardSetUpA(numbersOnBoard);
    printTwoD(numbersOnBoard);
    String[][] details = new String[6][6];
    boardDetails(details);
  }

  public static void boardSetUpA(int[][] twoD) {
    // Square with even size

    // even rows
    for (int row = 0; row < twoD.length; row++) {

      if (row % 2 == 0) {
        int num = twoD.length * (twoD.length - row);
        for (int col = 0; col < twoD[row].length; col++) {
          twoD[row][col] = num;
          num--;
        }
      } //
      else {
        int num = twoD.length * (twoD.length - (row + 1)) + 1;
        for (int col = 0; col < twoD[row].length; col++) {
          twoD[row][col] = num;
          num++;
        }
      }
    } // for row
  } //

  public static void printTwoD(int[][] array) {
    for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
      for (int column = 0; column < array[row].length; column++) {
        System.out.print(array[row][column] + "\t");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }

  public static void boardDetails(String[][] board) {
    for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
      for (int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++) {

        if (col + 2 == row || col + 1 == row * 2) {
          board[row][col] = "Lad"; // Append value
        } else if (col * 2 == row || row * 2 == col) {
          board[row][col] = "Cht"; // Append value
        } else {
          board[row][col] = "    ";
        }
      }

      board[board.length - 1][0] = "Start";
      if (board.length % 2 == 0) {
        board[0][0] = "End";
      } else {
        board[0][board.length - 1] = "End";
      }
    }
  }

  public static void printBoard(int[][] twoD, String[][] strTwoD) {
    // Printing
    for (int row = 0; row < twoD.length; row++) {
      for (int col = 0; col < twoD[row].length; col++) {
        System.out.print(twoD[row][col] + " " + strTwoD[row][col] + "\t\t");
      }
      System.out.println("\n");
    }
  }
}
```

I am creating a snakes and ladders game board and the game (will be finished later).I am trying to print the chutes/snakes and ladders on the board using the method boardDetails but it is not showing up, only the board from 1-36 is shown. Am I not calling the method? Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: "Am I not calling the method?" - Did you step through your code with a debugger already? That should answer the question, e.g. by setting a breakpoint in the method and waiting for that to be hit. - Having a look at your code you're calling `boardDetails()` which is adding the ladders and chutes to the passed array. But question to you: are you printing your board after calling that method? (Have a close look)

Comment: in addition to what Thomas said, if you want to print a board with the numbers and details, there's already a method `printBoard()` in your code that'll do that

Comment: Thanks everyone for the clues! Figured it out!